# How to whitelist IP/DNS of servers under loadbalancer?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, ip, load-balancing, whitelist

1. I have two servers (EC2 instances provided by AWS) under a loadbalancer (To be more specific ELB provided by AWS).
2. These servers run identical restful API code. (State is saved in mutual database).
3. Lets say these servers provide a service called X.
4. These two servers are in an autoscaling group (ASG provided by AWS) (meaning that if one dies or more computing power is needed - an additional server will be created).
5. Every server has it's own IP adress.

Lets say I am a consumer of this infrastructure. I send a HTTP POST request to a loadbalancer endpoint and i expect at some point to receive a HTTP POST request. The HTTP POST request would be sent from one of two servers under loadbalancer. How can I be sure that the HTTP POST request is sent from the service X and not by someone other? (Initially I want to whitelist IPs or DNSs to be safe)

Note that i can not simply white list IP adress of every machine under a loadbalancer since machines are killed and spawned regularly (assigning new IP adresses every time).

Comment: Configure ASG EC2 instances (in private subnet) to use NAT gateway with Elastic IP